# Access code igniter from an external php file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to access Code Igniter file from outside php file.

In my php file the destination folder is :

```
$doc_dir = '../admin/public/upload';
```

But my php file is located in the same level of admin folder(which is outside CI). 
So could you please suggest me how do I access the 'upload' folder (which is in CI) from student folder

```
    /admin
      public
      upload
   /student
      abc.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of these:
THis:

```
$doc_dir = dirname(__FILE__) . '/admin/public/upload';
```

Or This:

```
$doc_dir = explode("/",getcwd());
$doc_dir[count($doc_dir)-1] = "admin";
$doc_dir = implode("/",$doc_dir);
$doc_dir = $doc_dir."/public/upload";
```

One of the above approach will work.
The approach is to get the absolute path, so there are many ways to get absolute path, you can implement in your own way which you like.

Comment: Thanks a lot, both are working perfectly. Can you please guide me how to download uploaded documents (from a folder) within Code Igniter

Comment: yes, in your code igniter, make new page and do it using `readfile` function from the backend,. basically it will not have any view, you can search online